# Is it possible to edit the input in a UserForm in VBA?

Tags: vba, edit, userform

I am creating a yard management system to keep track of open parking spots in a lot. The userform allows the user to click on a spot in the map that is open and fill out a list of information about the truck going to that spot. Right now, if I make an error in the entry I have to redo the whole form, rather than just being able to edit the information I have already entered. Is there a way to do that without having to retype everything?

Here is the code for the user form:

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

    UpdateInfo.Show
    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UpdateInfo.Show
    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    lblInfo = ActiveCell.Value

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Set rngBDock = Range("BX7:CO7")
Set rngBulk = Range("BZ21:CG21")
Set rngTransT = Range("BF17:BY17")
Set rngTransT1 = Range("BG21:BY21")
Set rngTDock = Range("BL7:BW7")
Set rngEDock = Range("CP7:CT7")
Set rngNDock = Range("CU7:DC7")
Set rngFence = Range("CQ13:CV13")
Set rngNSide = Range("CW13:DB13")
Set rngGEO = Range("BG28:DD28")
Set rngNight = Range("CH21:DD21")
Set rngNewT = Range("DK31:DK65")
Set rngNewTl = Range("DI31:DI65")
Set rngOff = Range("BN40:CL40")
Set rngOffl = Range("BN42:CL42")
Set rng = Union(rngBDock, rngBulk, rngTransT, rngTransT1, rngTDock, rngEDock, rngNDock, rngFence, rngNSide, rngGEO, rngNight, rngNewT, rngNewTl, rngOff, rngOffl)

 If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        CellInfo.Show
        'ActiveCell.Value = cellFill
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            Call RealTimeTracker
        End If
    End If
```

```
Private Sub cmdOkUpdate_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 0 To lbxOption.ListCount - 1
    If lbxOption.Selected(i) Then j = j + 1
Next i
If j = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please select an option. ", , "Warning"
    Unload Me
    UpdateInfo.Show
ElseIf j = 1 Then
    NoFill = False
End If

strBOL = txtBOL.Value
strID = txtID.Value
details = txtDet.Value
opt = lbxOption.Value
currtime = time()
today = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
emp = TextBox1.Value

With ActiveCell
    spot = .Offset(-1, 0)
    If Len(spot) = 0 Then
        spot = .Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        spot = spot
    End If
End With


If NoFill = True Then
    cellFill = ""
ElseIf NoFill = False Then
    With Sheet5

    .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Date"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Location"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Category"
    .Range("E1").Value = "BOL"
    .Range("f1").Value = "Trailer #"
    .Range("g1").Value = "Details"
    .Range("H1").Value = "EE Name"
    
    .Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    .Range("A2").Value = currtime
    .Range("B2").Value = today
    .Range("C2").Value = spot
    .Range("D2").Value = opt
    .Range("E2").Value = strBOL
    .Range("F2").Value = strID
    .Range("G2").Value = details
    .Range("H2").Value = emp
    
    .Columns("A:H").AutoFit
    
    End With

    If Not IsEmpty(opt) Then
        cellFill = opt & " " & vbCrLf & "BOL (last 5 digits): " & strBOL & " " & vbCrLf & "Trailer # " & strID & " " & vbCrLf & details & "EE Name" & emp & " " & vbCrLf
        ActiveCell.Value = cellFill
        Call RealTimeTracker
    End If
    
End If


Unload Me
Sheet1.Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Leah, please take the [tour]. We also need to see your VBA code added to the question to be able to help you.

Comment: Okay thank you. I added the VBA code for the form. Is it helpful to see any other code?

Comment: Not sure about more code, but I think we need more information. When do you know you have made an error? After you have clicked to the next screen in the userform? Or after you have completed one entire userform "entry"? When you submit an entry, I'm assuming it saves to an Excel spreadsheet somewhere... does it also update data being displayed on this truck parking map?

Comment: What is the host application? Are you using Access?

Comment: The information displays both on the map and on another excel sheet. I believe this would be after completing one entire userform "entry". Sometimes a truck will have to change from the status of full to empty so I would ideally be able to just click on that trucks' "spot" on the map and there would be an option to edit the info already in there rather than having to redo the input. Right now when you click on a parking spot, the form will come up asking if you would like to update or clear the spot or cancel. If you choose update, it will take you to another form to enter the details.

Comment: I would like to add an edit button that pulls up the next form (that you would get to after clicking update) but with the details already in there from what had been entered so you can just change the status for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is. Obviously, when you have entered information for a parking lot in the user form, you store it somewhere. So, on a click on `update` (for that spot) you read the information from that storage to the user form, edit it, and save it again.

Comment: When I click on update a new blank form comes up which will overwrite what I had entered before. How do I get it to come up with the information I had already entered because then, yes, it would be straightforward to edit the information from there and save again?

Comment: It is impossible to give any concrete suggestion due to lack of information about your system. If you can locate and show us the code that saves the form data on one hand, and the code that opens the empty form on the other hand, maybe something turns up that could helps us suggest something. Are you the programmer of the system or are you   a user (without knowledge of the program)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am attempting to modify someone else's original program. I am not very familiar with VBA so am learning as I go. I believe I have added the code you asked for above.

Comment: Ideally, I would like the user to be able to edit the information from the "map" sheet where the userform comes up vs. the other sheet where the information is also fed. The map sheet also shows the information from the form after submitted.